# reading matrices cotaining dictionaries in python

Tags: python, matrix, nlp

I have two matrices (I want them for part of speech tagging). The first one contains the pos tags probabilities and the second contains the words probabilities. I need to extract numbers and sum the matrices. The problem is when I call each cell the string part appears, too. But I need the numbers. How can I call them. (Is this a correct way of making matrices? if not, how can I correct it with tags in heads of rows and columns?)

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[{'ARTART':0}],[{'ARTN':1}],[{'ARTV':0}],[{'ARTP':0}],
          [{'NART':0}],[{'NN':0.13}],[{'NV':0.43}],[{'NP':0.44}],
          [{'VART':0.65}],[{'VN':0.35}],[{'VV':0}],[{'VP':0}],
          [{'PART':0.74}],[{'PN':0.26}],[{'PV':0}],[{'PP':0}],
          [{'NULLART':0.71}],[{'NULLN':0.29}],[{'NULLV':0}],[{'NULLP':0}]]).reshape(5,4)
          #print (A)

B = np.array([[{'ARTflies':0}],[{'ARTlike':0}],[{'ARTa':0.36}],[{'ARTflower':0}],
          [{'Nflies':0.025}],[{'Nlike':0.012}],[{'Na':0.001}],[{'Nflower':0.063}],
          [{'Vflies':0.076}],[{'Vlike':0.1}],[{'Va':0}],[{'Vflower':0.05}],
          [{'Pflies':0}],[{'Plike':0.068}],[{'Pa':0}],[{'Pflower':0}]]).reshape(4,4)
#print (B)
#print (A[4][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this task by using just 2 dictionaries, one for each array which you are currently making:

```
A = {'ARTART':0, 'ARTN':1, 'ARTV': 0} # and so on
```

Then you can grab the values of each entry in the dictionary with:

```
A_val = A.values()
```

And finally you can sum the values with:

```
A_sum = sum(A_val)
```

Comment: It should be a matrix

Comment: And also I have to sum the rows of the first matrix with the columns of the second one

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  Do you want to sum row 1 from A with column 1 from B, row 2 from A with column 2 from B, and so on?

Comment: I have to sum the first element of the first row with the first element of the first column, the second element of the first row with the second element of the second column and so on

Comment: Since the shape of matrix B is not (4,5), how will you deal with the last element of each row in matrix A?  Regardless, if you just want to get values for any element in an array with the structure you have provided, the following will work: list(A[0][0].values())[0].  But I really think you should consider using a more appropriate data structure.